# HTML5 scoped styles on parent (scoping) element

Tags: css, html, scope

I'm reading through the HTML5 specification and for the [`scoped`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#attr-style-scoped) attribute on the `style` elements, it specifies:

> The `scoped` attribute is a boolean attribute. If present, it indicates that the styles are intended just for the subtree rooted at the `style` element's parent element, as opposed to the whole `Document`.
>
> A style sheet declared by a `style` element that has a `scoped` attribute and has a parent node that is an element is scoped, with the scoping element being the `style` element's parent element.

I'm trying to determine whether the scoping element can be accessed through the scoped style sheet, or just the children nodes of the subtree of the scoping element.

I copied [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#A_scoped_stylesheet) from MDN and modified it a bit:

```
<article>
    <div>The scoped attribute allows for you to include style elements mid-document. Inside rules only apply to the parent element.</div>
    <p>This text should be black. If it is red your browser does not support the scoped attribute.</p>
    <section>
        <style scoped>
            section {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <p>This should be red.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p>Another section here</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

When I ran the example in a supporting browser (only Firefox at this time), the text `This should be red` is still red. However, there are no `section` elements as children of the  scoping element. Also, "Another section here" was not red, so therefore the style only applied to the scoping element.

Can someone confirm if this behaviour is in accordance to the specification or a bug in Mozilla's implementation?

Comment: _“for the subtree rooted at the style element's parent element”_ – if `section` is the _root_ element of that subtree, that makes it _part_ of that subtree.

Comment: Ah, what a wonderful new way to produce browser inconsistencies.

Comment: @MrLister I guess the solution is not to use the parent element in the selector, **if** this will cause inconsistencies.

Comment: @joeytje50 The problem is that in non-conformant browsers, the style is not scoped at all; it affects all the elements in the whole document. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mM63W/1/). This makes `scoped` useless until literally all browsers support it.

Comment: @MrLister couldnt put it better myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTML 5.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) doesn't define any `scoped` attribute. But the [HTML 5.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/document-metadata.html#attr-style-scoped) says:

> The scoped attribute is a boolean attribute. If present, it indicates that the styles are intended just for the subtree rooted at the style element's parent element, as opposed to the whole Document.

In your case, the root of the subtree is the `<section>` element containing the `<style>` element. The root is part of the tree and the style `color:red;` is applied to it.

So, on this example, the the Mozilla implementation is conform with the standard.

Comment: Perhaps you meant <style> where you said <script>?

Comment: That makes the answer significantly clearer: +1.   So, in HTML 5.0, the `<style>` element was only permitted in metadata context (inside `<head>`).   However some browsers (eg IE 11) have permitted `<style>` to be used in the `<body>` of a document without any scoping implied by its location.   HTML 5.1, which is still a draft, a feature which is not upward upward-compatible with that permissive interpretation (as @MrLister points out.)